# Eigenvalues of sum of two fuchsian matrices

Tags: eigenvalues, similarity

Dear mathoverflow users,
I am trying to solve a problem concerning eigenvalues and sum of matrices.
In particular: consider the expression
$$
A=\frac{E}{x-x_1}+\frac{F}{x-x_2},
$$
and suppose to know eigenvalue and eigenvectors of both $E$ and $F$. Applying a similarity transformation, a new matrix $A'$ is retrieved
$$
A'=B^{-1}AB=\frac{E'}{x-x_1}+\frac{F'}{x-x_2}
$$
(it has been verified that the poles do not change after the application of the similarity), with
$$
B=1-P+\frac{x-x_2}{x-x_1}P,\quad P=u_iv_j^\dagger,
$$
where $u_i$ is a right eigenvector of $E$ and $v_j$ is a left eigenvector of $F$.

What is possible to say about the eigenvalues (and maybe eigenvectors) of $E'$ and $F'$? In particular, do the eigenvalues remain unchanged?

Thank you very much for all the help you will give me.

Kindest regards

Comment: I think you need to be clarify the roles of $x$, $x_1$ and $x_2$.   Are they constants or variables?  If variables, do they appear in $E$ and $F$?

Comment: $x_1$ and $x_2$ are constants, while $x$ is a variable. Sorry for the unclear notation.

Comment: it seems you define $E'=B^{-1}EB$ and $F'=B^{-1}FB$, and then of course the eigenvalues do not change.